# Does The Flash have a (theme) sound/music?

Tags: comics, dc

Does The Flash have a significant sound that is his? Since he runs so fast he can create a sonic boom, but nothing comparable to Batman and his little theme music, Iron Man and the sounds of his repulser rays, The Hulk 'Hulk Smash'. Seeing as how there has yet to be a Flash movie, there really hasn't been much sound effects to the comics other than a few games.

Comment: The has been a Flash tv series, and he showed up in Smallville.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MS4_Z84-rRE (wrong Flash though :(

Answer (score 2):

Flash had a TV show on CBS that ran a full season from 1990-1991.  Like most shows, this one had [an opening musical theme](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa9b7ZQ3Zkw).  The theme was reminiscent of the Batman movie theme, martial with lots of brass.

Answer (score 0):

The theme from the live Flash show was actually "Batman to the Rescue'" a track from the Batman movie soundtrack.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that it was the case?

Comment: This is not true at all.  They were both composed by Danny Elfman, but they are not the same. [Batman to the Rescue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mESN0nRuqK8), [Flash TV theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ghrNMiBU2A)

Comment: It seems like a different arrangement, but my source was the original broadcast credits and my VHS tapes. The VCR is down right now, or I would double-check. I'll post if I locate my DVDs.